# Nearly-unit-distance graph (UDG) density

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, discrete-geometry

> ***Q1***. How dense can a nearly-unit-distance graph be?

Let points sit in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

A *unit-distance graph* [UDG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_distance_graph)
"connect[s] two points by an edge whenever the distance between the two points is exactly $1$."

An upper bound on the density (number of pairs at distance $1$)
is $O(n^{4/3})$.

Let $0 < \epsilon \ll 1$.
I would like to loosen the "exactly" criterion and allow edges in an ~UGD
that are within $\epsilon > 0$ of $1$. Then the density
is the number of pairs within distance $1 + \epsilon$.

> ***Q2***. Does this immediately lead to $\Omega(n^2)$ behavior?

I.e.,

> ***Q3***. Is there a set of $n$ points such that
>   $\Omega(n^2)$ of them (some fraction of $n^2$ of them)
>   are within $1+\epsilon$ of one another?

Comment: Would it be worth adding a definition of density to this problem?  I assume it means the number of nodes within (say) an area $n\times n$ (equivalently, within distance $n$ of the origin, since a constant factor is concealed in the asymptotic notation).

Comment: @hardmath: There is no constraint on area. It is difficult to arrange many points close together; area bounds are not significant.

Comment: Following the link you gave to "unit-distance graph", the "density" is the number of edges in such a graph containing $n$ nodes.

Comment: @hardmath: Yes; you got it. Sorry for not making that more clear, and thanks for clarifying for others.

Comment: So density is, even under the relaxed requirement, trivially bounded above by $O(n^2)$.

Comment: The more interesting issue is the lower bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let half the points be tightly clustered about $(0,0)$ and the other half around $(1,0)$, i.e. within $\epsilon/2$ of the respective endpoints.

Then we have $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor \cdot \lceil n/2 \rceil$ edges of length between $1-\epsilon$ and $1+\epsilon$.  Thus asymptotically we can arrange $n^2/4 + O(1)$ such edges using $n$ points in the plane.

This is not the best possible fraction of edges.  We could get $n^2/3 + O(n)$ edges by clustering points as equally as possible about the three vertices of a unit equilateral triangle.

Comment: Nice construction---Thanks!